# I want to connect multiple cloud sql instance having private ip to my local machine or locally on Mysql workbench then how can i do that..?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, mysql-workbench, google-cloud-sql, cloud-sql-proxy, ibm-cloud-sql-query

I want multiple sql cloud instances to be connected to be connected to msql workbench and if possible without the use of virtual machine even if the solution is there by using virtual machine then do let me know

I have connected one cloud sql instance having private ip to mysql workbench by port forwarding but dont know how to add another cloud sql instance.

Comment: How do you perform port forwarding? Do you use Cloud SQL proxy?

Comment: To access Cloud SQL via a private IP requires access from a VPC. That means you must port forward from your local machine to a system running in the VPC and then to Cloud SQL. Solution: setup multiple port forwarding configurations.